# Return documents starting from ID, sorted by timestamp

Tags: elasticsearch

Say I have an index with the following documents:

```
{
    "id": "8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:02"
}
{
    "id": "0ebeb7b1-dcd0-4b37-a70d-fa7377f07f8c",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:03"
}
{
    "id": "ea779299-1781-4465-b8a1-53f7b14fbe0c",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:01"
}
{
    "id": "3624a119-4830-4ec2-a840-f656c048fc5c",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:04"
}
```

I need a search query that returns documents from a specified `id`, sorted by `timestamp` up to a limit (say 100). So given the `id` of `8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e`, the following documents will be returned (in this exact order, note that document with `id` `ea779299-1781-4465-b8a1-53f7b14fbe0c` is missing because its timestamp is earlier than the document I'm looking for):

```
{
    "id": "8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:02"
}
{
    "id": "0ebeb7b1-dcd0-4b37-a70d-fa7377f07f8c",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:03"
}
{
    "id": "3624a119-4830-4ec2-a840-f656c048fc5c",
    "timestamp": "2022-10-18T00:00:04"
}
```

I know how to do this in two queries by first getting the document by its `id`, and then another query to get all the documents "after" that document's `timestamp`, but I'm hopeful there's a more efficient way to do this using one single query?

Note that the index is expected to have tens/hundreds of millions of documents, so performance concerns are a factor (I'm unsure what "work" ES is doing under the covers, such as sorting first and then visiting each document to check the `id`), although the cluster will be sized appropriately.

Comment: I'm curious about how would you got this id without timestamp.

Answer (score -1):

You can use below `bool` query which will give you your expected result. `match_all` inside `must` will return all the documents and `term` inside `should` clause will boost the document where `ID` is matching.

If your `id` field is defined as `keyword` type then use `id` only in term query and if it is defined as `text` and `keyword` both then use `id.keyword`.

```json
{
  "size": 100,
  "sort": [
    {
      "_score": "desc"
    },
    {
      "timestamp": {
        "order": "asc"
      }
    }
  ],
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_all": {}
        }
      ],
      "should": [
        {
          "term": {
            "id.keyword": {
              "value": "8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e"
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Forgive me if I'm wrong but, this doesn't look like it would filter OUT documents that have a `timestamp` value earlier than the timestamp value of the document with `id` `8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e`? It looks like it will return every document in the index ordered by timestamp, and just put `8e8e3c0c-5d1d-4a3c-a78a-1bd2d206b39e` first?

Comment: Ahh ok.. My bad i took your question in wrong way. Let me check on this and update my answer.